# Hide UIView using alpha when user starts scrolls on UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, alpha

`viewController` is composed of 2 main views. A container view and a table view.

The container view is the top section with all the labels such as the day and score.

I want this container view to hide when a user starts scrolling through the days of the table view.

**So far I have:**

1. Hooked up an `IBOutlet` for this container view so I could reference it in the code.
2. Conformed to the `UIScrollViewDelegate`
3. Implimented all required methods for the `UITableView`

I know `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. Without a "proper" `UIScrollView` I am confused how to go about using the `scrollViewDidScroll` method and changing the container view alpha to 0 when I am scrolling in the tableView.

I also want the alpha to return to 1 when the user stops scrolling.

thanks.

**Note I am not using a UITableViewController**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: FYI - you could use command+s to take simulator screenshot.

Comment: You can use `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` and `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:` to check scrolling and stops scrolling. And change alpha.

Comment: NOTE: I dont have a UITableViewController

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a UITableViewController instead of a UIViewController and then drag a UIView in  the header section of the UITable. This will cause the UIView to get out of the way on scrolling right out of the box with no coding at all.

Comment: this is a great idea which ill certainly use next time but i'd like to keep it how it is at the moment. Thanks ill upvote u

Comment: @Mikael , just for future reference, if I drag a UIView into the header section such as the one I have (with multple labels) will I be able to change the label texts as you would change normal labels?

Comment: @CescSergey , Yes because the UIView is not reusable so you can just have IBOutlets to it just like you have now. Just by way of argument if you have a UITable it's much better to use a UITableViewController it will make your life much easier and prevent many surprise bugs. The way to think about it is that Apple did the coding for you and they presumably code better then we do :).

Comment: @Mikael Your input is great thanks a lot man. One final thing,by any chance off the top of your head do you know of any apple sample code of this?

Comment: You don't need any code just drag a UIView in the header of the table and it will scroll of the page when the user scrolls.

Answer (score 2):

If you already set your **UITableViewDelegate** IBOutlet your controller you will receive all UITableViewDelegate methods from your **UITableView** as well as all **UIScrollViewDelegate** methods, should you implement them.

If you would like to hide a particular view when the user starts scrolling I'd use the **-scrollViewWillBeginDragging** method

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        someView.alpha = 0.0f;
    }];
}
```

If you would like to show it again after the user stops scrolling, just use the method **-scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        someView.alpha = 1.0f;
    }];
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but only the text on the container view is disappearing and not the "container" (a white rectangle is left behind). All the labels are embedded inside this container. Is there someway to fix this?

Comment: Is your container view a part of the UITableView? Is it set as the UITableView's header or is it a standalone view?

Comment: Then it should hide itself and all of its child views. I'd check IBOutlets connections. I don't see the exact layout so I can only speculate as to what may be wrong.

Comment: You also need to offset the table at the same time at the view disappears for this to work. Right now you are hiding the view but it's still there.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following methods directly in controller. They will work :

```
// called on start of dragging (may require some time and or distance to move)
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;

// called on finger up if the user dragged. decelerate is true if it will continue moving afterwards
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;
```

Answer (score 1):

What have you made UIScrollViewDelegate?

I just took a UITableViewController in my current project and added UIScrollViewDelegate

```
 @interface YourTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

then stuck a comment in

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

and it called once as required (scrollViewDidScroll: will fire repeatedly). So I presume calling one of the UIView animateWithDuration: methods will complete the task you require?