# Make view disappear while scrolling

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I have two views, one UIView and one table view. I want that when is scroll down the table view the UIView disappears and when I scroll back up it appears again. How can I do this without using a table view controller?

Comment: might that solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575326/hide-uiview-starting-from-bottom-on-scroll sound like the same to me.

Comment: else this sounds helpful for your problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725750/hide-uiview-using-alpha-when-user-starts-scrolls-on-uitableview